# Pyomo constraints and model execution issues when modeling from mySQL database

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, pyomo

I have written a pyomo code in python to help me with a linear programming problem. I posted about it earlier, but my question was understandably too broad. I've worked on the code and hope that I can get some help here with how to correct some of the issues.

Goal: I am trying to optimize the growth of many different organisms in my lab.

Pretext: I have written a code that prompts the user to pick from a list of ~50 organisms they want to grow. They can pick as many as they want. Then it prompts them to pick the number of 'lots' that they want to grow for each of those. Then it selects what days they want to start step 3 of the process and what days they want to start step 4. It skips steps 1 and 2 because those are not constrained by spatial resources like steps 3 and 4 are. The code then queries a mySQL database that has a large predictions database built from a Gaussian Machine Learning project we did a few months back. This database lists the yield that would be achieved for each mold grown at each duration of days in step 1, 2, and 3. (Step 4 is just harvesting).

I am going to paste all parts of the code that come after the user input has collected because at this point, I'm not really sure where my issue is coming from...

The majority of issues I'm having are with the variables and constraints not being able to process boolean and/or the variables not being initialized.

```
# Get the start and end dates from the dates dictionary
start_date_1 = dates["start_date_1"]
start_date_2 = dates["start_date_2"]
end_date_1 = dates["end_date_1"]
end_date_2 = dates["end_date_2"]

#incubation_start_date_range = (start_date_1, start_date_2)
#harvest_date_range = (end_date_1, end_date_2)

def date_range_to_int(start_date, end_date):
    start_ordinal = start_date.toPython().toordinal()
    end_ordinal = end_date.toPython().toordinal()
    return list(range(start_ordinal, end_ordinal+1))

#incubation_date_range = date_range_to_int(incubation_start_date_range[0], incubation_start_date_range[1])
#harvest_date_ranges = date_range_to_int(harvest_date_range[0], harvest_date_range[1])

# Retrieve information from the gp_predictions table
query = "SELECT mold_id, plate_days, seed_days, incubation_days, pk, `lot*weeks`, predicted_average_yield_per_liter FROM gp_predictions"
cursor.execute(query)
prediction_list = cursor.fetchall()

# Create a model
model = ConcreteModel()

# Define sets
model.selected_mold_ids = Set(initialize=selected_mold_ids)
model.lots = Set(initialize=range(1,len(lots)+1))
model.incubation_start_dates = Set(initialize=range(start_date_1, start_date_2+1), within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.harvest_dates = Set(initialize=range(end_date_1, end_date_2+1), within=NonNegativeIntegers)

#print(incubation_start_date_range)
# Define the decision variables
model.plate_start_dates = Var(model.selected_mold_ids, within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.seed_start_dates = Var(model.selected_mold_ids, within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.inc_start_dates = Var(model.selected_mold_ids, within=model.incubation_start_dates)
model.plate_days = Var(model.selected_mold_ids, within=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=6)
model.seed_days = Var(model.selected_mold_ids, within=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=6)
model.incubation_days = Var(model.selected_mold_ids, within=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=10)
model.harvest_start_dates = Var(model.selected_mold_ids, within=model.harvest_dates)

# pk function
def pk_for_mold_ids(mold_ids, prediction_list):
    selected_predictions = filter(lambda x: x[0] in mold_ids, prediction_list)
    if not selected_predictions:
        print("No matching mold ids found in the prediction_list.")
        return []
    pk_list = [x[4] for x in selected_predictions]
    return pk_list

def is_weekend(date):
    date_obj = datetime.fromordinal(int(value(date)))
    if date_obj.weekday() >= 5:
        return True
    return False

# Helper function to check if a value is within a given range
def within_range(value, min_val, max_val):
    return value >= min_val and value <= max_val

# Helper function to retrieve min and max plate days for a given mold_id
def get_plate_days_range(mold_id):
    for x in prediction_list:
        if x[0] == mold_id:
            return x[1], x[2]
    return None

# Helper function to retrieve min and max seed days for a given mold_id
def get_seed_days_range(mold_id):
    for x in prediction_list:
        if x[0] == mold_id:
            return x[3], x[4]
    return None

#pk model
model.pk = Set(initialize=pk_for_mold_ids(list(model.selected_mold_ids), prediction_list))

# ---- Model Execution --- #
model.obj = Objective(expr = sum(prediction_list[i][5] * model.lots[i] for i in model.selected_mold_ids),sense=minimize)

# Constraints
def plate_days_range(model, i):
    min_plate_days, max_plate_days = get_plate_days_range(i)
    return min_plate_days <= model.plate_days[i] <= max_plate_days

def seed_days_range(model, i):
    min_seed_days, max_seed_days = get_seed_days_range(i)
    return min_seed_days <= model.seed_days[i] <= max_seed_days

model.plate_days_range = Constraint(model.selected_mold_ids, rule=plate_days_range)
model.seed_days_range = Constraint(model.selected_mold_ids, rule=seed_days_range)

def plate_days_constraint(model, i):
    return model.seed_start_dates[i] == model.plate_start_dates[i] + model.plate_days[i]

model.plate_days_constraint = Constraint(model.selected_mold_ids, rule=plate_days_constraint)

# Define the constraint for seed start date occuring before incubation start date
def seed_before_incubation_constraint(model, i):
    return (model.seed_start_dates[i] + model.plate_days[i]) == model.inc_start_dates[i]

model.seed_before_incubation_constraint = Constraint(model.selected_mold_ids, rule=seed_before_incubation_constraint)

def harvest_after_incubation(model, i):
    return model.harvest_dates[i] == model.inc_start_dates[i] + model.incubation_days[i]

model.harvest_after_incubation = Constraint(model.selected_mold_ids, rule=harvest_after_incubation)

def plate_seed_weekday(model, i):
    return is_weekend(model.plate_start_dates[i]) and is_weekend(model.seed_start_dates[i])

model.plate_seed_weekday = Constraint(model.selected_mold_ids, rule=plate_seed_weekday)

def harvest_weekend(model, i):
    return is_weekend(model.harvest_dates[i]) == True

model.harvest_weekend = Constraint(model.selected_mold_ids, rule=harvest_weekend)

def unique_incubation_start_dates(model, i, j):
    if i != j:
        return model.inc_start_dates[i] != model.inc_start_dates[j]
    else:
        return Constraint.Skip

# Constraint: Seed start date must be the same for lots of the same mold id
def same_seed_start_date(model, i):
    # Get the mold id for the current mold
    mold_id = i[0]
    # Initialize a variable to store the seed start date
    seed_start_date = None
    for j in model.selected_mold_ids:
        # If the current mold id is the same as the mold id we're checking
        if j[0] == mold_id:
            # If we haven't set the seed start date yet, set it to the current seed start date
            if seed_start_date is None:
                seed_start_date = value(model.seed_start_dates[j])
            # Otherwise, fix the current seed start date to the previous value
            else:
                model.seed_start_dates[j].fix(seed_start_date)
    return Constraint.Skip
model.same_seed_start_date_constraint = Constraint(model.selected_mold_ids, rule=same_seed_start_date)


def same_plate_start_date(model, i):
    # Get the mold id for the current mold
    mold_id = i[0]
    # Initialize a variable to store the plate start date
    plate_start_date = None
    for j in model.selected_mold_ids:
        # If the current mold id is the same as the mold id we're checking
        if j[0] == mold_id:
            # If we haven't set the plate start date yet, set it to the current seed start date
            if plate_start_date is None:
                plate_start_date = value(model.plate_start_dates[j])
            # Otherwise, fix the current plate start date to the previous value
            else:
                model.plate_start_dates[j].fix(plate_start_date)
    return Constraint.Skip
model.same_plate_start_date_constraint = Constraint(model.selected_mold_ids, rule=same_plate_start_date)


print('Pre solution check')

solver = SolverFactory('gurobi')

solver.solve(model, tee=True)

results = SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model)
if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) and (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
    print("Optimal solution found!")
else:
    print("Solver returned non-optimal or infeasible solution")

print(solver.solve(model, tee=True).solver.status)
print(model.obj()) 
for var in model.component_objects(Var, active=True):
    varobject = getattr(model, str(var))
    for index in varobject:
        print(varobject[index], varobject[index].value)
```

I've tried listing the variables as value(model.xxx). When that happens it says it is uninitialized.
I've tried initialized the variables (see the var section which has 6, 6, and 10) and it says it can't solve Boolean.
I've tried not listing them as value(model.xxx) and I'll get some combination of the two.

I understand that the LP nature of things is complicated but I didn't expect this to get tripped up when it seems so close to being complete. The complaints aren't that rigorous (no weekends, plating comes before seed, which comes before incubation, the ranges should be within what the user provided, etc...).

I feel confident that once the syntax is right, this should be pretty straight forward. I am just in a death spiral and feel like I'm mangling my code now...

Answer (score 0):

You have some significant problems with linearity in the model.  Before that, I'd recommend you start with something small that glosses over some of the difficulties you are having, which are specifically how to handle weekends and "same mold in lot" stuff.  Comment out some of those constraints, stuff some small sample data in lists / dictionaries (to take the db stuff out of the loop for a bit) such as:

```
molds = ['mold a', 'mold b']
seed_start_dates = [1, 5]
incubation_start_dates = [4, 10]
harvest_start_dates = [...]
harvest_value = {10: 1.5, 11: 1.7, ..., 30: 1.0}
```

and whatever key variables are to make a simpler model run and work through that.  Note `harvest_value` is indexed by total days to be part of your objective function.

Forget about weekends and lots for a sec.  Building **that** model will get you started.

Then, for the bigger model, forget about lots with same mold for a bit, that will be tricky, I'd focus on how to handle weekends.  (aside, you don't have `lots` modeled at all, you just have variables for each individual mold type.... but save that for later)

You cannot inject your function `is_weekend()` into the mix because it is evaluating variables and is a conditional statement based on the value of a variable.  That is **illegal** in LP.  The values of the variables are unknown when those constraints are built, so they must end up as simple linear expressions, hence the challenge.

Having particular day-indexed things not fall on certain days is quite tricky.  The simplest approach would be to just scale things up a bit and not worry about weekends.  This might work in general, unless everything is very fine-grained with few times that you overlap a weekend.

Example:  If this is the set of days with weekends as marked below:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
          x x              x  x
```

Then a first cut that alleviates need for extreme creativity is just to index by *work days* and scale up, so these would be your values:

```
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
                x x              x  x
val : 1 2 3 4 5     6 7 8  9  10       11    (basically the work days)
```

and then when you need the "total days" just take `int(val * 7/5)` when you get the `harvest value`.  If the total time in `seed` + `incubate` is a couple weeks, this should be totally adequate for predictive model inputs and might risk being off by +/- 2.  Thoughts?

Comment: I will definitely try and take it step by step instead of all the constraints at once. That is a good idea. The weekend aspect is quite important though and if that is removed, I don't think this system would be any better than the current method we have which is scheduling by hand. In other words having a person review the database and sort of guess and check what arrangements seem to work the best. Either way, I can try and sort that out later. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @Encker I just thought about this again...  not to pile on ... :)  I didn't think about how you described your objective function earlier.  It sounds like you have a predictor model that gives some yield ~ fn(seed days, incu days) and that function is non-linear.  That's going to be an issue as well.  There are alternatives/approximations.  You could find the best for each variable (or their total) separate from the model and then just penalize for "days away from the best" by some weighting.  Would that work or is something more precise needed?

Comment: Maybe LP isn't the way I need to tackle this then... its not really a function that I'm trying to utilize, its moreso the information from the database that should be accessed. I'd like for the model to iterate through all the potential combinations of dates (based upon the constraints) and present the 'schedule' that is the most optimal. I use a unit referred to as 'lot_weeks' that reflects productivity. The lower lot_weeks is, the more efficient that selection was for that specific organism. I hope that makes sense but ultimately, those calculations are all already performed by the SQL DB

Comment: I just need the model to do those iterations as I think there is a lot of efficiency that is lost when I do it on my own. With the inputs of: mold_id, # lots (per mold_id), and acceptable date ranges, I was hoping to then access the DB and have it analyze the potential choices based upon the input and return the most optimal schedule. A big constraint, if it wasn't clear earlier, is that only one organism can begin incubation per day and only one organism can be harvested per day.

Comment: Ok.  So, if I'm interpreting this correctly, the key challenges is making the schedule with knowledge of the optimal dates from some source.  You certainly can take an LP approach to this and just use a simple linear penalty for "days away from optimal" for each activity... key is to avoid some nonlinear function (like gaussian or other) as the objective...  "days  off" is doable.

Comment: Can you update your problem statement (or comment) on the rough scale of things you are working on...  it might inform the approach.  What is the range of days in your planning horizon?  (20?  200?).  How many organisms are active at one time?

Comment: Sure thing: minimum days = 7, max = ~30. If this works though, there's some merit to planning out months at a time though... Currently we do it almost week by week.

Organisms at a time is anywhere from 5-10. I'd only schedule at most 3 different organisms per week though. At most, you'd do 4 lots of the same organism at a time too. Each one being on a separate day for incubation and harvest. 

We have a bunch that are active because they grow anywhere from like 9-45 days. Average is between 2 and 3 weeks though.

Comment: With regards to your other comment regarding the key challenges. Another way I would put it is: Its impossible to achieve perfect optimization due to the constraints of weekends, only able to process one organism a day, and the complexity of growing multiple organisms at once. Since it is impossible to be perfectly optimal, I'd like to know what schedule (layout of what days to perform certain steps for each organism) is the most optimal. The DB has all the info I need to determine optimization. Its just too much data to handle without assistance.

Comment: On the contrary...  I think it is totally possible to write a *schedule optimizer* that takes as inputs the optimum seed & incubation days for each organism and produces the best schedule to achieve that for multiple lots, avoids weekend, etc. as long as it is agreed that some "penalty factor/weighting" can be used to score misses of the seed/incubate day targets -- which can be different by organism.  I'd use your db to generate those weights and then set it aside, put in the stuff you want to grow and produce the best schedule

Comment: Drop a comment if you are still working on this and looking for some help in doing so.  I've got some ideas on this that might be better discussed in another forum.  Cheers!

Comment: I'm definitely still working on this! Had some other work stuff come up but have not found a solution. I've scaled things down and am ironically now stuck with the fact that I don't have a 'solver' installed. Once I figure out how to get ipopt or glpk going, I'd would very much welcome your support.

Comment: If you haven't had a chance to get something working, LMK if you are interested in some small-fee contract support.  I have built similar models and I'd be happy to code something up that I think you'd find very helpful in schedule management.